# Sufficient conditions for: convergence in probability implies convergence in $L^p$?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, convergence-divergence

Is this specific condition *sufficient* for the mentioned statement,

Convergence in probability  $X_n \rightarrow X$ implies convergence in mean $L^p$ when the probability density function (PDF) of $X_n$ be such that:

$$f_{X_n}(x) = 0, ~\text{for} \quad |x| > x_0  ~ \forall ~n>N$$

for some $N > 0$.

Comment: The probability distribution function $f$ of a r.v. $X$ should tend to $1$ when $x\to +\infty$.

Comment: That is the value for that range.

Comment: I mean if $f$ is a distribution function of $X$ then there has no such $x_0$ such that $f_X(x)=0$ for $x>x_0$.

Comment: I cannot get your point?

Comment: If $f$ is a distribution function of $X$ then $f$ is non-decreasing on $\mathbb R$ and $f(x)\to 1$ as $x\to +\infty$. So, if there has an $x_0$ such that $f(x)=0$ for all $x>x_0$ then $\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x)=0$ and this is contradiction.

Comment: It is the probability density function of $X_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

W.l.o.g., assume that $N=0$. First, Denote $Y_n =|X_n-X|$, since $X_n\to X$ in probability we have $Y_n \to 0$ in probability. We know that the congergence in probability implies the convergence in distribution, that is $X_n \to X$ in distribution and it follows $\lim_{n\to \infty} \mathbb P(X_n \in [-x_0, x_0])= \mathbb P(X\in [-x_0, x_0])$. It follows from the assumption $\mathbb P(X_n \in [-x_0, x_0])=1$ that $\mathbb P(X\in [-x_0, x_0])=1$ and hence $|X|\leqslant x_0$ a.s.

Next, for $\epsilon >0$ arbitrarily,
$$\sup_{n}\mathbb E|Y_n|^{1+\epsilon}=\sup_{n}\mathbb E |X_n-X|^{1+\epsilon} \leqslant C_{\epsilon}(\sup_{n}\mathbb E|X_n|^{1+\epsilon} + \mathbb E|X|^{1+\epsilon})$$$$\leqslant C_{\epsilon} \sup_{n}\mathbb E|X_n|^{1+\epsilon} + C_\epsilon x_0^{1+\epsilon}.$$
On the other hand, 
$$\mathbb E|X_n|^{1+\epsilon} =\int_{-x_0}^{x_0}|x|^{1+\epsilon}f_n(x)dx\leqslant x_0^{1+\epsilon}\int_{-x_0}^{x_0}f_n(x)dx = x_0^{1+\epsilon} \;\mbox{ for all } n$$
as the density function $f_n\geqslant 0$ on $\mathbb R$. Combining with the argument above we get $\sup_{n}\mathbb E |Y_n|^{1+\epsilon} <\infty$ for all $\epsilon>0$.

Now for each $p\geqslant 1$, Using [Vallée-Poussin's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability), we get that $(|Y_n|^p)_n$ is uniformly integrable (e.g., choosing $G(t)=|t|^{p+1}$ and then $\epsilon =p^2+p-1$).

Note again that $|Y_n|^p\to 0$ in probability then $|Y_n|^p\to 0$ in $L^1$ by [Vitali's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_convergence_theorem), or equivalently $|Y_n|\to 0$ in $L^p$ for all $p\geqslant 1$.

Therefore, with your settings, we get a stronger conclusion is that $X_n \to X$ in $L^p$ for all $p\geqslant 1$.

Comment: Thanks @ntt. I cannot follow the conclusion part. Can you explain the conclusion part of your answer; I mean clearly mention that as we have for convergence in mean square: $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{E[|X_n - X|^r]} \rightarrow 0.$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: $X_n\to X$ in $L^p$ for all $p\geqslant 1$, then your problem is a special case when $p=2$.

Comment: Not this pasrt; before last sentence you have two sentence, I mean that part.

Comment: You could check Vitali's theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_convergence_theorem and then appy for $(|Y_n|^p)_n$.

Comment: Here we combine Vitali's theorem and "de la Vallée-Poussin theorem" about a criterion for uniform integration https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability.

Comment: the only point that you mentioned in your answer that I could not follow is: "$|Y_n|^p\to 0$ in probability then $|Y_n|^p\to 0$ in $L^1$ by [Vitali's theorem][2], or equivalently $|Y_n|\to 0$ in $L^p$ for all $p\geqslant 1$"; could you please explain it?

Comment: First, since $(|Y_n|^p)$ is uniformly integrable and $|Y_n|^p\to 0$ in probability , we get from Vitali's theorem that $|Y_n|^p\to 0$ in $L^1$ (to imagine more easily, you can denote $Z_n=|Y_n|^p$).

Second, $|Y_n|^p\to 0$ in $L^1$ means $\mathbb E\big||Y_n|^p -0\big| \to 0$, this is rewritten that $\mathbb E\big||Y_n| -0\big|^p \to 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Answer is yes (follows directly from bounded convergence). Here's an elementary argument that only relies on the definition.

Convergence in probability means
$$ P(|X_n -X|>\epsilon) \to 0$$.

First we show that this implies that $|X|\le x_0$ a.s. If this is clear, skip to next paragraph. Otherwise:
\begin{align*}  P(|X|>x_0+\epsilon) &\le P(|X-X_n| +|X_n|>x_0+\epsilon) \\&=P(|X-X_n|+|X_n|>x_0+\epsilon,|X_n-X|\le \epsilon) + P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)\\
& = P(\epsilon+|X_n|>x_0+ \epsilon) + P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)\\
& = 0 + P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)\\& \to 0.
\end{align*}

Next estimate:

\begin{align*} 
E[|X_n - X|^p]&=E[|X_n-X|^p,|X_n-X|>\epsilon]+\epsilon^p P(|X_n-X|\le \epsilon).\\
& \le (2x_0)^pP(|X_n-X|>\epsilon) + \epsilon^p.
\end{align*}

Send $n\to\infty$ to obtain

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} E|[X_n-X|^p]=\epsilon^p.$$

But $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, and result follows.